# Python Pillow Image.save encoding error 5

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using `PIL` version 9.2 and attempting to convert a batch of images from their original formats (JPG & PNG) into `webp` formatted images. I'm having an issue with one image in particular, and I'm thinking that it has to do with the file size itself; but not certain.

Here's my function I'm using:

```
from PIL import Image
import json

def convert_to_webp(source):
    try:
        destination_path = str(Path(source).with_suffix('.webp')
        image = Image.open(source)
        if 'A' in image.mode:
            alpha = image.split()[-1]
            image.putalpha(alpha)
        image.save(destination, format="webp", optimize=True, lossless=False, quality=100, method=6)
        image.close()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(image.filename, e)
        print(json.dumps(image.info, indent=4))
        return False
```

The output for the failed image (thrown exception):

```
path/to/image.jpg encoding error 5
{
    "jfif": 258,
    "jfif_version": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "dpi": [
        300,
        300
    ],
    "jfif_unit": 1,
    "jfif_density": [
        300,
        300
    ],
    "photoshop": {
        "1005": {
            "XResolution": 300.0,
            "DisplayedUnitsX": 1,
            "YResolution": 300.0,
            "DisplayedUnitsY": 1
        }
    },
    "adobe": 100,
    "adobe_transform": 1
}
```

Is there something I need to do to the image before I convert it to `webp`?

Comment: Mmmm, interesting. Maybe try saving as a PNG and see what happens... Is your JPEG image taller/wider than 16,000 pixels?

Comment: I believe this is in pixels, when I run `print(image.size)` I get back `(31251, 10417)`

Comment: Webp only allows up to 16,383 x 16,383 pixels.

Comment: So, in this case I'm assuming I would have to resize/compress the image and then convert it to webp?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. I cannot know if that is acceptable to you. It will permit you to use `webp` format, but I don't know if the quality/resolution is adequate for you or your users/clients.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I appreciate the advice

Comment: No problems. Try resizing and saving and see if it works ok. If it does, add and accept your own answer for future readers.

Comment: in my case i set format to png while saving and somehow works and extention of file still same .webp